# Does Lighthouse work in isolation or does it require internet access?

Tags: lighthouse

I couldn't find explicit statements on this, and just wanted to be sure.

Does Lighthouse work in isolation, or does it require connection to some Google service, or at least internet connectivity?

I've used Lighthouse (via Chrome Dev Tools) for years to analyze live websites. However I haven't really used it on localhost while developing websites; I was always under the impression it needed some Google service to do it's thing.

On running localhost tests it looks like it runs as-is, in isolation. However when publishing said website and running the same audit on the online version, some numbers differ (mainly Performance), and I guess this would be due to different server properties/configuration. Perhaps I've answered my own question.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58394704/2397550